# Extracting SQL table to excel splits long text attributes to different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, extract

I ran a simple SQL query in SSMS and got a table with long text in a certain column (failuresympthomdecsription_f). when I try to copy to excel, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upgPy.png) (attached). it completely masses up my data :(
it splits the text to 3 different lines.

I can't find the SQL command/ synthax to handle this,
though I'm sure there is one...

any ideas?
thanks!

Comment: This is normal if your text contains tab and/or enter.  You may not be able to do copy/paste a keep right format.  Quick answer is to remove enter.  You may link your excel to Sql (excel will pull data from sql), or you can write a console app that generate an Excel file.

Answer (score 2):

It's probable you have tabs and/or CRs in the text field, which Excel interprets as a new cell/row when pasting.  Try

```
SELECT REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(failuresympthomdecsription_f, char(9), ' '),
    char(13), ' '),
char(10), ' ') AS failuresympthomdecsription_f...
```

in your query to convert them into spaces.

Comment: i have a few thousands records - so it's not realistic to find the char location...
any idea on how to do it throughout the table?

Comment: Huh? This finds and replaces everything for you in the resulting recordset, what do you mean "find the char location"?